# How to get JSON object (as 'GET') from url using $resource in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm an beginner in angularjs and don't have any idea about web services either. My requirement is something like this:

I have to get a JSON object from my url http://mylocalhostname.dev/users/list?city_id=12

I'm absolutely clueless...Please help me out by modifying my code.

Thanks in advance. Here's my JS code:

```
'use strict';

var services = angular.module('services', ['ngResource']);

services.factory('dataFactory', ['$resource','$http', '$log',
        function ($resource, $http, $log) {
                return {
                    getAllUsers: function(){
                        return  $resource('http://mylocalhostname.dev/users/list',{city_id:12}
                            ,{
                                locate: {method: 'GET', isArray: true, transformResponse: $http.defaults.transformResponse.concat(function(data, headersGetter)
                                  $log.info(data.UsersList[0]);
                                  return data.UsersList[0].userName;
                                })}
                            }
                        );
                    }
                } 
    }]);
```

when i test i get this message in my console :

GET http://mylocalhostname.dev/users/list?city_id=12 200 OK 164ms   angular.js (ligne 7772)
(in color red)
(an empty string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I realize this is an ancient question, but still unanswered, and it appeared at the top of a search I just did, so hopefully this can close that particular loop)

Simple example of a controller retrieving data from a simple factory, where the factory is using $resource to access a locally-hosted file and returning contents of file back to the controller.

The factory:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('myFactory', ['$resource', function($resource) {
     return function(fileName){
       return $resource(fileName, {});
     };
  }]);
```

The controller:

```
'use strict';
var fileToGet = 'some/path/to/file.json';
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('myController', function($scope, myFactory) {
   var getDefs = new myFactory(fileToGet).get(function(data) {
      $scope.wholeFile = data;
      // $scope.wholeFile should contain the entire JSON-formatted object

      $scope.someSection = data.section;
      // $scope.someSection should contain the "varX" and "varY" items now

      $scope.myStringX = JSON.stringify(data.section.varX);
      // get the stringified value 
   });
});
```

The JSON-formatted file:

```
{
  "someVar": "xyz",
  "someArray": [
    {
      "element0A": "foo",
      "element0B": "bar"
    },
    {
      "element1A": "man",
      "element1B": "chu"
    }
  ],
  "section": {
     "varX": 0,
     "varY": "yyyy"
  }
}
```